# Algorithm for directed Eulerian cycle

Tags: python, directed-graph

I've used python to write the code below to find the Eulerian cycle. If there is no edge available (because it's been traversed already) to the next node, then my elif statement should go through my cycle, find the last node with unexplored edges, and continue from there.

However, when I run this program, starting from '0', the cycle I get is ['0', '3', '2', '1']. Since the next node after 1 is 0, my elif statement should recognise that there is no edge between 0 and 3. But because the cycle stops at 1, I am obviously doing something wrong.

In mydict, '2': '16' means that 2 has edges leading to 1 and 6.

```
mydict=  {'0': '3', '1': '0', '2': '16', '3': '2', '4': '2', '5': '4', '6': '58', '7': '9', '8': '7', '9': '6'}


def pathway(node,mylist):
    if len(mydict[node]) == 1: 
        mylist.append(node)
        next = mydict[node]
        mydict[node] = ''
        pathway(next, mylist)
    elif len(mydict[node]) ==  None:
        prev = previous(mylist)
        pathway(prev, mylist)       
    else:
        while len(mydict[node]) > 1:
            mylist.append(node)
            next = mydict[node][0]
            mydict[node] = mydict[node][1:]
            pathway(next, mylist)
    return mylist

def previous(mylist):
    while False:
        for i in range(len(mylist)-1,-1,-1):
            node = mylist[i]
            if len(mydict[node]) == None:
                mylist.remove(node)
            else:
                return node


print pathway('0',[])
```

Could someone please point out my error? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `'2': '16'` mean `2` has edges to both `1` and `6`? Anyway, I think your code should have `if node in mylist: return mylist` to terminate early, and `for edge in mydict[node]: pathway(edge, mylist)` to recurse over the edges rather than having `previous()`. (NB: Might do a fuller reply later)

Comment: @Ken Y-N If I followed your first suggestion, then wouldn't my code terminate incorrectly if mylist contained 2, even though 2 had one more unused edge?

Comment: Oops, I realised I didn't understand the algorithm you were trying to implement. Anyway, one problem I see is `len(mydict[node]) == None` - this will never be true as 0 does not equal `None`. `not mydict[node]` is the canonical way to test for an empty string or list. Furthermore, `previous()` always returns `None` as `while False:` means it never enters the loop, but I'm not really sure what the best way to fix this is...